# Whatsapp cloud API enable Whatsapp_business_messaging permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, whatsapp

I have been trying to send Whatsapp messages using cloud API, but its expecting to enable Whatsapp_business_messaging permission which is by default disabled when associating with any app that has been created.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/get-started#get-access-token.

I didn't find any documentation pertaining to enable the above mentioned permission. Kindly assist.

Comment: have you been able to solve the problem? I'm at the same point as you...

Comment: I'm also stuck at the same problem. Any luck so far?

Comment: @Vineet   Can you how you sloved this Issue I am stuck at same

Comment: I had to go with selenium and python approach for whatsapp web, since i was running on tight schedule

Answer (score 0):

In order to enable the permission you need to follow these steps:

```
1. Sign into the Meta Business Suite.
2. Locate your business account in the top-left dropdown menu and click its Settings (gear) icon.
3. Click Business settings.
4. Navigate to Accounts > WhatsApp Accounts.
5. Select the appropriate WhatsApp Business Account.
6. Select the WhatsApp Account Access tab.
7.Click the +Add people button.
8.Select the appropriate system user and assign appropriate access levels on the WhatsApp Business Account.
```

Make sure you generate your system token after updating the permissions so it is generated with the new permissions you need.

More details can be found at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/business-management-api/get-started/#whatsapp-business-account-control

Answer (score -1):

**Edited**

WhatsApp cloud API is Now Public!

According to their docs,

To start using it for development prepose

1. [Register as a Meta Developer](https://developers.facebook.com/micro_site/url/?click_from_context_menu=true&country=EG&destination=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fapps&event_type=click&last_nav_impression_id=0eWTtJe0bsyTwecHw&max_percent_page_viewed=43&max_viewport_height_px=625&max_viewport_width_px=1366&orig_http_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fwhatsapp%2Fgetting-started%2Fsigning-up&orig_request_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fajax%2Fdocs%2Fnav%2F%3Fpath1%3Dwhatsapp%26path2%3Dgetting-started%26path3%3Dsigning-up&region=emea&scrolled=true&session_id=1lIQWLmyLorQ0V7QZ&site=developers)
2. [Enable two-factor authentication for your account](https://developers.facebook.com/micro_site/url/?click_from_context_menu=true&country=EG&destination=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fhelp%2F148233965247823&event_type=click&last_nav_impression_id=0eWTtJe0bsyTwecHw&max_percent_page_viewed=43&max_viewport_height_px=625&max_viewport_width_px=1366&orig_http_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fwhatsapp%2Fgetting-started%2Fsigning-up&orig_request_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fajax%2Fdocs%2Fnav%2F%3Fpath1%3Dwhatsapp%26path2%3Dgetting-started%26path3%3Dsigning-up&region=emea&scrolled=true&session_id=1lIQWLmyLorQ0V7QZ&site=developers)
3. [Create a Meta App](https://developers.facebook.com/micro_site/url/?click_from_context_menu=true&country=EG&destination=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fdevelopment%2Fcreate-an-app%2F&event_type=click&last_nav_impression_id=0eWTtJe0bsyTwecHw&max_percent_page_viewed=43&max_viewport_height_px=625&max_viewport_width_px=1366&orig_http_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fwhatsapp%2Fgetting-started%2Fsigning-up&orig_request_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fajax%2Fdocs%2Fnav%2F%3Fpath1%3Dwhatsapp%26path2%3Dgetting-started%26path3%3Dsigning-up&region=emea&scrolled=true&session_id=1lIQWLmyLorQ0V7QZ&site=developers): Go to developers.facebook.com > My Apps >
   Create App. Select the "Business" type and follow the prompts on
   your screen.
4. From the App Dashboard, click on the app you would like to connect
   to WhatsApp. Scroll down to find the "WhatsApp" product and click
   Set up.
5. the onboarding process performs the following actions:

- our App is associated with the Business Manager that you chose
- **A WhatsApp test phone number is added to your business. You can use this test phone number to explore the WhatsApp Business Platform
  without registering or migrating a real phone number.**

for more info please refer to [whatsapp cloud getting started](https://whatsapp/getting-started) docs

Answer (score -1):

Yes, WhatsApp Cloud API is now public.

With the Cloud API, businesses can directly get access to WhatsApp Business API from Facebook, in minutes.

For more info check out this [WhatsApp Cloud API Guide](https://m.aisensy.com/blog/whatsapp-cloud-api-introduced/).

Answer (score -1):

I recently made an open-source python wrapper for newly  WhatsApp Cloud API to help developers easily get started, You really wanna have a look at it https://github.com/neurotech-HQ/heyoo.

**Installation**

```bash
pip install --upgrade heyoo
```

Here is the sample code to send a message ;

```py
>>> from heyoo import WhatsApp
>>> messenger = WhatsApp('TOKEN',  phone_number_id='104xxxxxx')
>>> messenger.send_template('hello_world', 'your number')
```

For Javascript developers please have a look into [Heyhooh](https://github.com/JS-Hub-ZW/heyooh)

**Installation**

```bash
npm install heyooh
```

Here how sending to send messages;

```py
import WhatsApp from heyhooh
let messenger = new WhatsApp('TOKEN',  phone_number_id='104xxxxxx')
messenger.send_template("hello_world", "255757xxxxxx")
```

For PHP Developers [whatsappcloud-php](https://github.com/pro-cms/whatsappcloud-php)

**Installation**

```bash
composer require zepson/whatsappcloud-php
```

Here how the code to send a message;

```php
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use zepson\Whatsapp\WhatsappClass;

$token = 'YOUR_META_WHATSAPP_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN';
$phone_number_id = '10726082513218961';
//send message
$tsap = new WhatsappClass( $phone_number_id, $token);

$sendtsap = $tsap->send_template('hello_world', '255654485755');
 
print_r($sendtsap);
```